# If value is zero, numeral.js prints space instead of zero

Tags: javascript, numeral.js

When the value is zero, `numeral.js` prints a space instead of 0.00. I need this case to print 0.00.

This prints space:

```
let x = numeral(0).format('0.00');
console.log(x);
```

if the value is *not* zero, this works fine. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: File an issue over on https://github.com/adamwdraper/Numeral-js/issues (after checking to see if it's a known problem)? But at the same time, why do you need numeral.js for this? `(0).toFixed(2)` works perfectly fine.

Comment: I recommend using default API Intl or toFixed to solve because this library is no longer under maintenance